# Azure Portal and Entra access/permissions problem AADSTS16000

Tags: azure, microsoft-entra-id, entra

I created a free account on portal.azure.com yesterday. However, most views are returning me a permissions problem.

```
The logged in user is not authorized to fetch tokens for extension 'Microsoft_AAD_IAM' because the user account is not a member of tenant
```

It looks like I do not have access to my own Tenant. I can see his ID but he is not in the list.

I have the same problem in Portal as well as in Entra

I can't even set up a support request because of Microsoft_Azure_Support

Below are a few screenshots:

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1355627/cannot-login-to-azure-portal-aadsts16000-user-acco and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1377925/issue-while-logging-in-to-azure-entra-portal-aadst

Comment: @Rukmini great thanks. ReRegistration through https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/ helps me (even without card verification) it now looks like it's working properly - I have my own Tenant. Previously I register directly on portal.azure.com

Comment: Can I post it as an answer?

Comment: Yes you can. I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note** that: If you are signing in to the Azure Portal by using your personal account then by default it will be connected to Microsoft Services tenant (f8cdef31-a31e-4b4a-93e4-5f571e91255a).

And hence your TenantID is `f8cdef31-a31e-4b4a-93e4-5f571e91255a`

- So, in this default tenant, there will be no directory associated with it.
- This is a standard tenant without any directory associated and hence you cannot perform any actions.
- You must be the administrator to perform administrative actions.

**To resolve this issue**, create your own tenant by using access https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/ to create a free Azure account.

[image]

You will be the Global Administrator for the tenant you created.

**Reference:**

[Issue while logging in to Azure/Entra portal - AADSTS160021/AADSTS16000/AADSTS50020 - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1377925/issue-while-logging-in-to-azure-entra-portal-aadst) by Shweta Mathur